# NoClassDefFound error for com/aspose/pdf/BaseParagraph with aspose pdf 23.1 jdk17 jar in Eclipse

Tags: noclassdeffounderror, aspose.pdf

I am trying to work with aspose PDF jar and I am not able to get past the NoClassDefFound error for aspose pdf jar. I am using aspose imaging as well as aspose words jar. Both these do not have these, but only aspose PDF does.
Compilation is successful, but on run time I hit this issue.
I am using eclipse IDE

Any help is highly appreciated as I am running out of options to solve this issue.

**Steps tried : **

- Switched workspace
- Deleted the entire project
- Made sure there is only one class with that name (essentially only one jar)
- Classpath entries are fine in eclipse. Buildpath->libraries->add external jars. also order and export is selected.